# Using css selector lastchild and :after together in angular2

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<h2 class="title-main">
     <span class="title-inside">A</span>
     <span class="title-inside">B</span>
     <span class="title-inside">C</span>
     <span class="title-inside">D</span>
     <span class="title-inside">E</span>
     <span class="title-outside">F</span>
     <span class="title-outside">G</span>
</h2>
```

CSS:

```
:host/deep/.title-main {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    .title-inside {
        &:after {
            content : '-';
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the output like this

```
A-B-C-D-E-F G
```

I don't want the - for the last child. I want the output like this

```
A-B-C-D-E F G
```

i tried many options. For eg. one of them which i tried

```
title-inside:last-child ::after {
           content: ''
    }
```

But this is not working. Could anyone please help me

Comment: I tried like this also. That is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `:not` with `:nth-last-of-type()`

```css
.title-main {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title-inside:not(:nth-last-of-type(3))::after {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title-main">
  <span class="title-inside">A</span>
  <span class="title-inside">B</span>
  <span class="title-inside">C</span>
  <span class="title-inside">D</span>
  <span class="title-inside">E</span>
  <span class="title-outside">F</span>
  <span class="title-outside">G</span>
</h2>
```

Here is the [SASS version](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/58230e7f1012d66fee4fde40beb3026d)

```css
:host/deep/.title-main {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    .title-inside {
        &:not(:nth-last-of-type(3)){
           &::after{
            content : '-';
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried ur approach. But no hypen is coming for other child also

Comment: I've just updated the SASS version, I've forgot the `&::after` take a look again

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i dont know, in my case this is not working

Comment: I have updated my html. Could you please see that. I want that style to be applied to the last child of title-inside. @dippas

Comment: Ya it worked. I used :nth-child(5). I tried with urs also it is working fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Since `:nth-*` and `last-child` selectors use the actual element type and not class name, I think it is better to use a class selector.

By using the `::before` pseudo instead, combined with the sibling selector `+`, it does not matter how many items each class has, it will always count right.

```css
.title-main {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.title-main  .title-inside + .title-inside::before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title-main">
     <span class="title-inside">A</span>
     <span class="title-inside">B</span>
     <span class="title-inside">C</span>
     <span class="title-inside">D</span>
     <span class="title-inside">E</span>
     <span class="title-outside">F</span>
     <span class="title-outside">G</span>
</h2>


<h2 class="title-main">
     <span class="title-inside">A</span>
     <span class="title-inside">B</span>
     <span class="title-inside">C</span>
     <span class="title-outside">D</span>
     <span class="title-outside">E</span>
     <span class="title-outside">F</span>
     <span class="title-outside">G</span>
</h2>
```

---

SASS

```
:host/deep/.title-main {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    .title-inside {
      &+.title-inside {
        &::before{
          content : '-';
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want the hypen after E

Comment: @Priya Updated my answer with an explanation that might help